# Odoo - Inherit action from base module

Tags: xml, odoo-9

I want to **inherit** the below **action** from **base** and change the **view_id**.

```
<record id="account.action_account_payments" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Payments</field>
        <field name="res_model">account.payment</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form,graph</field>
        <field name="context">{'default_payment_type': 'inbound'}</field>
        <field name="domain">[('partner_type', '=', 'customer')]</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_account_payment_tree"/>
</record>
```

Is the below code, the correct way to do it? Does it inherits or overrides the action? I just want to inherit the action and change view_id and call it in a button click.

```
<record id="module_name.record_id" model="record_model">
   <field name="name">New record name</field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using alternative solution.

Ex:

```
    <record id="payment_tree_view" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
        <field eval="1" name="sequence"/>
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
        <field name="view_id"  ref="view_payment_tree"/>
        <field name="act_window_id" ref="account.action_account_payments"/>
    </record>
    <record id="payment_form_view" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
        <field eval="2" name="sequence"/>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_payment_form"/>
        <field name="act_window_id" ref="account.action_account_payments"/>
    </record>
```

> You need to create ir.actions.act_window.view , in which give your
>   custom form & tree view.

This may help you.